# Virtualbox - start vm failed after update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have updated VirtualBox to Version 5.1.18 r114002 (Qt5.5.1) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. To virtualize everything (Kali, Windows 10).
I encounter the following error:

> RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)
>
> The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox.
>   The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful.
>   Executing
>
> '/sbin/vboxconfig'
>
> may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and
>   the PUEL version of VirtualBox.
>
> where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4
>   VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver
>   doesn't match the version of the user.

I have excuted `sudo '/sbin/vboxconfig'` and get:

> vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
>
> vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
>
> vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.

So, I've reinstalled Virtualbox several times and tried a lot of solutions. But the problem is not solved!

Comment: Have you rebooted your machine?  It is possible you have installed a new version of the kernel, but are not running it since you haven't booted since installation.

Comment: @JimD. Yes, I rebooted my machine.

Comment: True answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/900794/virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed-with-rc-1912-rc-1912

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your problem is a known one.
Did you already see following links:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=79035

http://mitreasorin.blogspot.co.uk/2016/08/upgrade-virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed.html

or looked on google for `RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912`.
I would also suggest you to post on https://forums.virtualbox.org your possible VirtualBox issues.
Hope this helps

Simon